# Исключение System.Net.Mail.SmtpException при отправке почты

Tags: asp.net-mvc, исключения, smtp, sendmail

При отправке письма на почтовый ящик выдает ошибку на:

> (Send(mail))..Разрешение вопросов, связанных с исключениями: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("login@yandex.ru", "Name");
mail.To.Add(account.Email);
mail.Subject = "Hello";
mail.Body = "Hello from Asp.net mvc";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.yandex.ru";
client.Port = 587;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("login@yandex.ru","password");

client.Send(mail);

db.Registration.Add(account);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Так себе html...

Comment: держите нас в курсе

Answer (score 0):

Недавно работала с отправкой email, вот так отправляется. В моём коде по большому счёту отличается только строка с портом, а также у Вас отсутствует smtp.EnableSsl = true.

```
    public static void SendEmail(string email, string text, string subject)
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("aspnet.confirmation@yandex.ru", "ASP.NET Blog");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(email);
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = text;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.yandex.ru", 25);
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("aspnet.confirmation@yandex.ru", "yourpassword");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
```

Дополнительно о переходе на SSL SMTP-сервером Яндекса можно почитать [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/237899/).

Answer (score 0):

Еще пару лет назад SMTP Яндекса перешел на SSL. Поэтому выставление соответствующего свойства `EnableSsl` в положение `true` обязательно. 
Далее, сперва попробуйте отправить с порта **25**, если не выходит то выставляйте порт **587**. Далее, убедитесь, что указанный email в поле from и с помощью которого вы авторизуетесь - одинаковы. В противном случае будет выброшено соответствующее исключение с описанием. Также попробуйте обернуть исполняемый код в блок `try_catch`, чтобы была возможность изучить возможное исключение. Вот пример кода:

```
public static void SendEmail(string title, string text, string emailTo, bool isBodyHtml = false)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.IsBodyHtml = isBodyHtml;
        mail.From = new MailAddress(ConstantsWeb.Email.Address.RobotEmail, ConstantsWeb.Global.CompanyName);
        mail.To.Add(emailTo);
        mail.Subject = title;
        mail.Body = text;
        mail.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(ConstantsWeb.Email.Server.Name)
        {
            Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConstantsWeb.Email.Address.RobotEmail, ConstantsWeb.Email.Address.RobotEmailPassword),
            Port = ConstantsWeb.Email.Server.Port,
            EnableSsl = ConstantsWeb.Email.Server.UseSsl
        };

        SmtpServer.Send(mail);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //do whatever...
    }
}
```

В данном примере настройки сервера берутся из констант, можно прописать их вручную, а лучше перенести в файл `web.config`